# Get trimmed size of of CCSprite

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I use a Zwoptex spritesheet+plist with trimmed sprite elements inside of the texture. From what i understand in order to not mess up animations cocos uses the "spriteSourceSize" and gives all sprites this size.

The question is how do i get the trimmed size from the sprite? "spriteSize" plist entry as opposed to the "spriteSourceSize"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

"textureRect" property.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.0/interface_c_c_sprite.html#aa793e1433058539e5664ffd3533ab928